# Null Pointer Exception when trying to add new object to array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, nullpointerexception

I have an array, moviearray, with logical size of 15 and physical size of 50.  I have the following code:

```
    for(int a=0;a<moviearray.length;a++)
            {
                if (moviearray[a]!=null)
                    {
                        if(moviearray[a].getTitle()==catAddTitle.getText())
                        {
                            moviearray[a].addExisting(Integer.parseInt(catAddNumber.getText()));
                            break;
                        }
                    }   
                else
                {
                    moviearray[a].setTitle(catAddTitle.getText());
                    moviearray[a].setNumber(Integer.parseInt(catAddNumber.getText()));
                    moviearray[a].setGenre(catAddGenre.getText());
                    moviearray[a].setYear(Integer.parseInt(catAddYear.getText()));
                    moviearray[a].setRating(catAddRating.getSelectedItem());
                    moviearray[a].setPrice(Double.parseDouble(catAddPrice.getText()));
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I am trying to have it so where when I enter a movie title into catAddTitle (text field), and it matches a movie currently in moviearray, it will increase the movie's amount element by the number entered in the textfield catAddNumber.  However, when I try doing this, it gives me a nullpointerexception on the line:

```
    moviearray[a].setTitle(catAddTitle.getText());
```

Example: one of my objects in the array has the elements "Hobbit/55/Adventure/2012/PG-13/10.00" (title, number, genre, year, rating, price).  What should happen is that when I enter "Hobbit" into catAddTitle and "3" into catAddNumber, it should change the number to "58" (despite the other textfield data). Thanks in Advance

Comment: By the way you should use `.equals()` to compare string rather than `==`. The later will return false for two distinct instances of Strings with the same content whereas `.equals()` checks the content.

Comment: @Pierre I didn't notice that, but I fixed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your else-branch - which is executed only if `moviearray[a] == null` -  you need to do

```
moviearray[a] = new YourObject();
```

first, i.e. create an instance of your class and store it in the array.

Comment: That fixed it.  I keep forgetting that it doesn't automatically make empty objects.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the String with equals() not with `==` Operator

change this line with

```
if(moviearray[a].getTitle()==catAddTitle.getText())
```

to

```
if(moviearray[a].getTitle().equals(catAddTitle.getText()))
```